# How to return specialized type from associated function in generic structs?

Tags: rust

I was trying to implement some kind of stack with a default type

```rust
pub struct Stack<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<T> Stack<T> {

  fn new() -> Self::<i32> {
    Self::<i32>(Vec::<i32>::new())
  }
}
```

However this won't compile, and gives an error like this:

```
error[E0109]: type arguments are not allowed for this type
 --> src\lib\stacks.rs:7:22
  |
7 |   fn new() -> Self::<i32> {
  |                      ^^^ type argument not allowed

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0109`.
error: could not compile `nullptr`
```

Did I made any errors in this piece of code? Thank you.

Comment: Within the `impl<T> Stack<T>`, `Self` refers to `Stack<T>` which means `Self::<i32>` is understood to mean `Stack<T>::<i32>` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9341e52bfff914b2a885d45e2bcc9c15

Comment: @kmdreko Thank for pointing that out for me! I thought the `Self` means `Stack` only.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you declared a generic `<T>` type stack, why would you try to force your `new()` method to always use a `i32`?

To make it really generic you should wait to pass its type only when instantiating:

```rust
pub struct Stack<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<T> Stack<T> {

  fn new() -> Self {
    Stack { 0: Vec::new() }
  }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Stack::<i32>::new(); // <- here
}
```

Besides that, the short way you've declared your struct `struct Stack<T>(Vec<T>);` will need you to use `0` to access the internal stack reference because you didn't give its field a name. It's up to you, but this way it would look a bit better:

```rust
pub struct Stack<T> {
    value: Vec<T>
}

impl<T> Stack<T> {

  fn new() -> Self {
    Stack { value: Vec::new() }
  }
}
```

Comment: I realized I have used the wrong approach, thank you for your advice anyways ;-)